# MIM CM REST API Service - Missing functionality? (compared to .Net Remoting API)

Tags: certificate, windows-identity

I am investigating the conversion from FIM .Net Remoting interface to MIM CM REST API.

However - there seems to be a lot of functionality missing, one example (there are numerous others):

```
- RequestOperations.Approve (approve a Request)

      -> the "Sample Enrollment Walkthrough" in the developer resources of the CM REST API only show the process for "auto approved"
```

So - what's the deal with this? Can the CM REST API only be used in conjunction with to the older .Net Remoting API? Or does the REST API in fact have all the old functionality and I only missed it?